# Error running 'Tomcat 9.0.38': Cannot load (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: java, rest, maven, tomcat, web-applications

This is my  web.xml file

```
    <servlet-name>Alien Applicationsssss</servlet-name>

    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>

        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>

        <param-value>com</param-value>

    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-name>Alien Applicationsssss</servlet-name>

    <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>
```

I have tried to uninstall, IntelliJ and java but that doesn't seem to work. this happens every time I try to run the application. I changed the path in the environment variable on my computer that didn't work.

this is the whole error message I get
Error running 'Tomcat 9.0.38': Cannot load C:\Users\yeahm.IntelliJIdea2019.2\system\tomcat\Tomcat_9_0_38_Alien_Applicationsssss\conf\web.xml: C:\Users\yeahm.IntelliJIdea2019.2\system\tomcat\Tomcat_9_0_38_Alien_Applicationsssss\conf\web.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)

The file that it tries to load does not exist. so my question is how can I configure tomcat to load in a specific folder or file that does exist?

*Solved*

I solved it by just deleting every instance of Tomcat 9.0.38 and downloading the latest version of tomcat.

Comment: Does the specified file exist?

Comment: it does not exist. I have no clue how to change the path to a file that does exist.